# Resize модального окна: css или jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css3

Делаю адаптивное модальное окно. Сверстала двумя способами: на css и jq. В том и другом случае есть проблемы.

1. Можно не вычислять ширину и высоту модального окна для каждой картинки в лайтбоксе, просто задать в css стиль для адаптивного изображения:

   ```
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
   ```

Решение простое, но не кроссбраузерное. В FF модальное окно при переключении прыгает по углам, когда меняются размеры картинки. В хроме все нормально.

1. Jquery. Создаю новую картинку и через нее получаю размеры каждой картинки в лайтбоксе. Если обратиться напрямую к изображениям  в галерее, то передаются текущие размеры изображений, а не фактические.

   ```
   $(".wrapper").click(function() {

       $(".modal-content, #modal-background").fadeIn();

         $('.modal-content img').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));

              mainScreenshot = $(".modal-content img");
          theImage = new Image();
          theImage.src = mainScreenshot.attr("src");

          winWidth = theImage.width;
          winHeight = theImage.height;
          $(".modal-content").width(winWidth);
          $(".modal-content").height(winHeight);
   });
   ```

Если остановиться на втором способе, то как сделать такое модальное окно адаптивным? 
Пробовала вычислять размеры модального окна через размеры окна браузера, не получается. Буду благодарна за идеи!

Comment: Всё, что можно сделать на css, надо делать на css.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap в помощь.

**Обвновление**

Вот здесь вроде как разжёвано даже: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=1669
А вообще, если занимаетесь версткой , используйте фреймворки с ними куда проще все делать и они кроссбраузерные.

Comment: @Максим147, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Для создания модального окна используйте jquery, как пример на Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Вот здесь вроде как разжёвано даже: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=1669

Comment: Спасибо за ответы) Я знаю про бутстрап (использую паттерны оттуда) и как делается модальное окно.  Мне нужно понять алгоритм, каким способом сделать модальное окно, чтобы   анимировать его размеры! Либо  на transition, либо  на animate.  Возможно, я в первый раз нечетко задала вопрос, поэтому перефразирую.
Как мне соединить два куска кода (мой выше) и код для ресайза отсюда
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio
и сделать через animate плавное изменение размеров модального окна, в зависимости от размера картинки?

Comment: На всякий случай скажу. что знаю про fancybox и и др., мне важно понять алгоритм самой, будут другие похожие задачи. Третий день уже гуглю и переписываю код)